# Angular Compiler options

Tags: angular, angular-compiler

I'm looking explanation for some **Angular Compiler options** that are listed [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.3.1/packages/core/src/linker/compiler.ts#L91-L109):

- useDebug - to switch on the debug
- **useJit** - not clear (used only in [one place](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/54e02449549448ebab6f255f2da0b4396665c6f0/packages/compiler/src/jit/compiler.ts#L146))
- defaultEncapsulation - to set default styles encapsulation
- **providers** - not really clear (is it the same to ngModule decorator?)
- missingTranslation - strategy what to do if translation key is missing
- enableLegacyTemplate - to support `template` tag (that is already deprecated)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### useJit

is whether codegen or interpretative mode is used.

***Codegen*** is default mode so we can see the output in browser development tools. In this mode angular transforms all statements collected during compilation to files with executable code in browser memory.

I know three places where this option is used

- Module factory generation https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.3.x/packages/compiler/src/jit/compiler.ts#L146

  `ng:///AppModule/module.ngfactory.js`
- Component factory generation https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.3.x/packages/compiler/src/jit/compiler.ts#L282

  `ng:///AppModule/Component_Host.ngfactory.js`

  `ng:///AppModule/Component.ngfactory.js`.
- `styleUrls` code generation https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.3.x/packages/compiler/src/jit/compiler.ts#L307

  `ng:///css/0app/app.css.ngstyle.js`

***Interpretative mode*** means that angular will work like interpreter.  Statements generated in previous steps(lexical analysis, parsing, semantic analysis, optimization) will be executed directly. Angular doesn't translate code to component and module ngfactories as it does in codegen mode. Instead angular uses special wrappers for factories i.e.

```
function _declareFn(
    varNames: string[], statements: o.Statement[], ctx: _ExecutionContext,
    visitor: StatementInterpreter): Function {
  return (...args: any[]) => _executeFunctionStatements(varNames, args, statements, ctx, visitor);
}
```

and then it will execute these wrappers each time when it's necessary.(For example when you handle event, when angular is running `updateDirectives`, `updateRenderer` etc) And each time `StatementVisitor` will be used to walk through all the statements.

Initially interpretative mode is also used for `DART` https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/2b34c88b69af8b0031fdb7006327bb8260e23dda#diff-ba3d6dc88c6e1cef871391a7843a614eR167 But now this mode is almost not used AFAIK.

---

### Providers

**If we have two providers with the same token, the second provider "wins"**.

So `providers` option is a great feature to override default [COMPILER_PROVIDERS](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.3.x/packages/compiler/src/jit/compiler_factory.ts#L48-L97)

For instance we can

1) customize `DomElementSchema`

- [Add custom elements and attributes to compiler schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42953118/add-custom-elements-and-attributes-to-compiler-schema)

2) use specific `DirectiveResolver` to override template

- [Using DirectiveResolver to alter @Component metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42413026/using-directiveresolver-to-alter-component-metadata)

3) override `ResourceLoader`

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13286

4) override `Parser`, `TemplateParser` to visualize the work of the compiler

- https://alexzuza.github.io/enjoy-ng-parser/

and so on...

We can't do the same with NgModule providers because compiler uses dedicated injector(JitCompiler injector in the picture below)  https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.3.x/packages/compiler/src/jit/compiler_factory.ts#L115 and the compilation happens https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.3.x/packages/core/src/application_ref.ts#L326-L329 before `@NgModule` providers are resolved https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.3.x/packages/core/src/application_ref.ts#L297

Let's say we have app like:

```
my-app
  level1
    level2
      level3
```

Then dependency resolution algorithm will look like:

[image]

If we use lazy loading for all levels https://plnkr.co/edit/AYExeiYRSQ4H8LiQEgKo?p=preview

```
my-app
  router-outlet
    level1
      router-outlet
        level2
          router-outlet
            level3
```

It will be transformed to

[image]

To simplify i omitted `router-outlet` injectors in the diagram.

For more details see the design docs:

- https://docs.google.com/document/d/1OEUIwc-s69l1o97K0wBd_-Lth5BBxir1KuCRWklTlI4

Comment: thank you very much for such a detailed answer! Several remarks: "codegen or interpretative" - still not clear, sorry. "I know three places" - but it's not a source code. And about providers: I thought we could do the same with `ngModule` providers, no?

Comment: @StepanSuvorov Updated answer

Comment: @StepanSuvorov You're right. it's only for jit compilation